# react native release apk crashes on RazorpayCheckout.open razorpay gateway

Tags: android, react-native, razorpay

I am new to react-native and payment gateway and creating an android app,
I am using 
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-native-razorpay": "^2.1.30",

also i linked the using react-native link react-native-razorpay

and imported package as

import RazorpayCheckout from 'react-native-razorpay';

and calling gateway as :

```
    RazorpayCheckout.open(options).then((data) => {
       .............
        alert(`Success: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
    }).catch((error) => {
        alert(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
    });
```

the code works when i am running the app in debug mode, but when i create apk using 
bundleRelease and assembleRelease.

apk works fine until i try to make payment.

My conclusion : when apk goes to the  RazorpayCheckout.open function call app crashes. I dont know how to debug that and hit a dead end here.

Comment: Once the Razor pay loader is opened and the app is getting closed?

Comment: Can u pls check the amount you are passing is in paise for example 601.23 should be 60123 if it goes with decimal then they would throw an error

Comment: check the amount you are passing.

Comment: I am facing the same too. I am passing the amount as 60123 only. when the Razorpay.open triggered. The app itself crashes/closes.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue as when I was canceling the Razor pay or when its going success app was crashing without any log.

**The solution is simple:-**

***1 step***
make a file name of proguard-rules.pro inside

```
android>app
that should be : android/app/proguard-rules.pro
then paste below code inside proguard-rules.pro file

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-dontwarn com.razorpay.**
-keep class com.razorpay.** {*;}

-optimizations !method/inlining/*

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  public void onPayment*(...);
}
```

***2 step***
go to android>app>build.gradle and find buildTypes
inside buildTypes>release add some lines

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true 
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

***3 step***

do the same as step 2 in debug also if you want to run APK in debug mode

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I just disabled the progaurd rules.
`enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false`